# Tensorflow 2.0 - do these model predictions represent probabilities?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, logistic-regression

I have a very simple Tensorflow 2 Keras model to do penalized logistic regression on some data. I was hoping to get the probabilties of each class, instead of just the predicted values of [0 or 1].

I think I got what I wanted, but just wanted to make sure that these numbers are what I think they are. I used the `model.predict_on_batch()` function from Tensorflow.keras, but the documentation just says that this provides a `numpy` array of **predictions**. However I believe I am getting **probabilities**, but I was hoping someone could confirm.

The model code looks like this:

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(features)                                                                    

model = tf.keras.Sequential([                                                                                              
    feature_layer,                                                                                                         
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01))                               
])                                                                                                                         
model.compile(optimizer='adam',                                                                                            
              loss='binary_crossentropy',                                                                                  
              metrics=['accuracy'])      

predictions = model.predict_on_batch(validation_dataset)

print('Predictions for a single batch.')
print(predictions)
```

So the predictions I am getting look like:

```
Predictions for a single batch.                                                                             
tf.Tensor(                                                                                       
[[0.10916319]                                                                                                           
 [0.14546806]                                                               
 [0.13057315]                                                                                                             
 [0.11713684]                                                                                    
 [0.16197902]                                                                                                              
 [0.19613355]                                                                                                             
 [0.1388464 ]                                                                                                   
 [0.14122346]
 [0.26149303]
 [0.12516734]
 [0.1388464 ]
 [0.14595506]
 [0.14595506]]
```

Now for predictions in a logistic regression that would be an array of either 0 or 1. But since I am getting floating point values. However, I am just getting a single value when there is actually a probability that the example is a 0 and the probability that the example is a 1. So I would imagine an array of 2 probabilities for each row or example. Of course, the Probability(Y = 0) + Probability(Y = 1) = 1, so this might just be some concise representation.

So again, do the values in the array below represent probabilities that the example or Y = 1, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values represented here:

```
tf.Tensor(                                                                                       
[[0.10916319]                                                                                                           
 [0.14546806]                                                               
 [0.13057315]                                                                                                             
 [0.11713684]                                                                                    
 [0.16197902]                                                                                                              
 [0.19613355]                                                                                                             
 [0.1388464 ]                                                                                                   
 [0.14122346]
 [0.26149303]
 [0.12516734]
 [0.1388464 ]
 [0.14595506]
 [0.14595506]]
```

1. Are the probabilities corresponding to each one of your classes.
2. Since you used `sigmoid` activation on your last layer, these will
       be in the range [0, 1].
3. Your model is very shallow (few layers) and thus these prediction probabilities are very close between classes. I suggest you add more layers.

## Conclusion

To answer your question, these are probabilities but only due to your activation function selection (`sigmoid`). If you used `tanh` activation these would be in range [-1,1].

Note that these probabilities are "binary" for each class due to the use of `binary_crossentropy` loss - aka 10.92% that class 1 is present and 89.08% that it is not, and so on for other classes. If you want the predictions to follow probabilistic rules (sum = 1) then you should consider `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: thanks for the info. Yeah, I had not connected the single neuron in the last layer with the single value for the probability estimate. That makes sense. Thanks for confirming my intuition here. I should submit a change request to the tensorflow docs, since prediction is not exactly the right term given the conditions above.

Comment: I might have not explained above well enough. Let me rephrase:
since you only have 1 output node, you will have 1 prediction number corresponding to the class (max 2 classes). The reason you have so many "predictions" is because you are predicting on batches, so your predictions are all on 1 class (generalized since that is what you hard coded) but for each batch item. The reason you see probabilities ([0,1]) is due to your activation function choice. If you have more than 2 classes, your final dense layer should have more nodes. Hope this is clearer!

Comment: Based on the above explanation, I assume your variable `validation_dataset` has 13 elements. If you want 2 probabilities, set the output layer to have 2 nodes and use `categorical_crossentropy` as `binary_crossentropy` won't give you probabilities which add up to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. Yes, I understand the math just fine, but understanding how the computing represents the math can be the challenge. Yes, I have a small batch against which to test, and that data was basically 0/1 outcome data. I could try this with `categorical cross-entropy` just to see what the output looks like.

Comment: Make sure to use 2 nodes rather than 1 in the last dense layer or else you will get all 1 at the output with categorical.

Comment: Oh right. Yes, good point. Haha, tensorflow would not give me an error if I had a single node, but the results would not be right. Good catch there :).

Answer (score 0):

If your dense layer is predicting classes you'll want to set the activation function to use `softmax` which returns a probability distribution (see https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/)

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```